# Function to delete all leaf nodes from Binary Search Tree

Tags: binary-search-tree

I would like to ask for corrections on that function. The problem is that it deletes more nodes than there are leaves. Means it is deleting all the leaves first, and then it is deleting the just created leaves.
Please, advise me how to correct it.
Leaf = node without children nodes.

```
typedef struct node {
    int key;
    node* left;
    node* right;
}node;

void BST::DeleteLeafs()
{
    if (root == nullptr)
        throw InvalidOperationException();
    else
        deleteLeavesHelper(nullptr, root);
}

void BST::deleteLeavesHelper(node* parent, node* n)
{
    if (n == nullptr)
        return;
    else
    {
        if (n->left == nullptr && n->right == nullptr)
        {
            n = nullptr;
            if (parent != nullptr)
            {
                parent->left = nullptr;
                parent->right = nullptr;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            deleteLeavesHelper(n, n->left);
            deleteLeavesHelper(n, n->right);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You write:

```
    if (n->left == nullptr && n->right == nullptr)
    {
        n = nullptr;
        if (parent != nullptr)
        {
            parent->left = nullptr;
            parent->right = nullptr;
        }
    }
```

One problem, you should deallocate the memory for `n`, otherwise you have a memory leak.  `n=nullptr;` is completely useless.

Another problem, you nullify pointers to both children of `parent`.  Instead, you need to nullify only the pointer to the correct child:

```
if (n->left == nullptr && n->right == nullptr) {
    if (parent != nullptr) {
        if (parent->left == n)
            parent->left = nullptr;
        else if (parent->right == n)
            arent->right = nullptr;
        else
            // raise some exception
    }
    // deallocate n
}
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. I have corrected it and it works.

Comment: but there is another issue. this function is called in a while loop (in the destructor). and at last it is supposed to delete the root (when root becomes leaf node), but it does not delete root. could you please give some solution for that?

Comment: Debug it and check why it doesn't delete root.

Comment: because I have to pass 'node* n' by reference.
I found the answer.